# Failed to get sum of a specific row in php

Tags: php, html, sql, mysqli

Failed to get total of students in a specific class from mysqli

Am trying to get the sum of students in a specific class from table. I have a code that gets duplicated rows so I want to count those rows based on the Id passed forexample if the Id passed is for a student in class seven, I want to count all rows in sigles which is the column name with seven and display the total number
Here is my code

```
<div class="bio">
                <span><b>Student's name: </b></span><span class="text-uppercase pl-3"><?php echo $row['student_name'] ?></span><br>
                <span><b>Position in class:</b></span> <span>47</span> out of <span>
                    <?php
                    $id = $_GET['id'];
                       $sql1 = "SELECT sigles, COUNT( sigles ) total_members FROM tbl_student GROUP BY sigles
                       HAVING total_members > 1;";
                       $res1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);
                      //  echo $total_members;
                      $count = mysqli_num_rows($res1);
                      echo $count;
                      
                       

                    ?>
                </span> pupils <br>
                <span><b>Division:</b></span> <span>1</span>
            </div>
```

this is how my database looks
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7Y1K.png)

so am expecting the answer to be 4 since they are 4 sevens in the column

Comment: What's happening instead? What have you tried to resolve the problem? Is this a PHP problem, an HTML problem, or a MySQL problem?

Comment: Show us what your database table looks like, example data and the expected result from that data, and it will be much easier for us to be ablet to help. We have no idea what the data looks like, what it contains, what you currently get and what you expect. You haven't described your actual issue

Comment: I have attached the image showing the structure of my db

Comment: Shouldn't it be `COUNT(sigles) AS total_members`?

Comment: yeah, that is how it is

Comment: It is not. It is `COUNT( sigles ) total_members` - at least that's what you posted

Comment: "I have attached the image showing the structure of my db"  - please add all clarification in text form

Comment: actually as was missing , thanks, but it is still giving the same output, is there a way I can echo total_members

Comment: you said _sum of students in a specific class from table_ .... i can see you have class id ... so can you try ```select class_id, count(student_id) as student_count from table-name group by class_id``` ... or  .... ```select class_id, count(student_id) as student_count from table-name where  sigles = 'seven' group by class_id```

Comment: I have implimented it but it brings a fatal error

Comment: If you want help with an error, you need to actually tell us what the error is!

Comment: The error is when I run the code I included in the question, am expecting to get the total number of duplicated values in a column called sigles, so as per now am expecting 4 as an answer but am getting 1 instead

Comment: "The error is" - which error? Are you really facing "a fatal error"? Then share the **full and exact** error message

Comment: I do not get any error but I do get a wrong answer, am supposed to get 4 but gets one instead

Comment: Why not add this information to the question, along with more details such that others can try to reproduce this problem?